# js remove specific element in two dimensional(2D) array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following DATA

```
folders = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'name',
        logo: 'logo',
        tasks: 
        [ 
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'blaas bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'name',
        logo: 'logo',
        tasks: 
        [ 
            {
                id: 3,
                text: 'blasdasda bla bla',
                done: true,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'name',
        logo: 'logo',
        tasks: 
        [ 
            {
                id: 5,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
        ]
    }
    ]
```

I got folders array that contains data on folders (id name etc) and array of tasks.
I want to get from the user the id of A task and remove that speicific task from the data.

I tried to do the following but it removing all the folder while I want to remove the specific task.

```
folders.filter( folder => folder.tasks.every( task => task.id != taskId ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ `splice`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

It will allow you to remove a specific element at a given index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.protorype.find()` and also `Array.prototype.filter()` like so:

```js
const folders = [
  {
      id: 1,
      title: 'name',
      logo: 'logo',
      tasks: 
      [ 
          {
              id: 1,
              text: 'blaas bla bla',
              done: false,
          },
          {
              id: 2,
              text: 'bla bla bla',
              done: false,
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      title: 'name',
      logo: 'logo',
      tasks: 
      [ 
          {
              id: 3,
              text: 'blasdasda bla bla',
              done: true,
          },
          {
              id: 4,
              text: 'bla bla bla',
              done: false,
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      id: 3,
      title: 'name',
      logo: 'logo',
      tasks: 
      [ 
          {
              id: 5,
              text: 'bla bla bla',
              done: false,
          },
          {
              id: 6,
              text: 'bla bla bla',
              done: false,
          },
      ]
  }
]

const taskId = 5;
const item = folders.find(item => item.tasks.find(({ id }) => id === taskId))
item.tasks = item.tasks.filter(({ id }) => id !== taskId)

console.log(folders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
folders.forEach( (folder) => {folder.tasks = folder.tasks.filter( task => task.id != taskId )})
```

Explanation:
Translating to English, this code is trying to change each folder, by keeping only the tasks whose id does not match the given taskID.
Whereas the code mentioned in the question is trying to modify the folders by keeping only those folders, all of whose tasks have id not matching taskID.

Comment: Please do up-vote / accept as answer if appropriate :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And here is another way of doing it in one line:

```js
const folders = [
  {id: 1,title: 'name',logo: 'logo',
   tasks: [ {id: 1,text: 'blaas bla bla',done: false,},
            {id: 2,text: 'bla bla bla',done: false,},]},
  {id: 2,title: 'name',logo: 'logo',
   tasks: [ {id: 3,text: 'blasdasda bla bla',done: true,},
            {id: 4,text: 'bla bla bla',done: false,},]},
  {id: 3,title: 'name',logo: 'logo',
   tasks: [ {id: 5,text: 'bla bla bla',done: false,},
            {id: 6,text: 'bla bla bla',done: false,},]}];


let task, tid=5;      // tid: target id of task to be removed
folders.some(({tasks},i)=>tasks.some((t,j,tsks)=>t.id==tid && (task=tsks.splice(j,1))));

console.log(task);    // the removed task
console.log(folders); // the folders array without that task
```

The script will only remove the first found task with a given `id==tid` number, assuming that `id` will not be used twice for different tasks.